# How do you create a default player for an enemy AI script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy AI script working that basically follows my player. Right now I have a "public GameObject player" that I have to assign manually by dragging my player prefab onto the slot. But I want to have a lot of enemies in the scene, so I don't want to have to do this manually for each one. How Can I give the EnemyController script a default player to follow?

I have a PlayerManager which I use to pass the position of my player to the enemy with:

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform target;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
    }
```

That part works fine. So my thinking was, just make a public variable for the player like this:

```
public GameObject player = PlayerManager.instance.player;
```

But that didn't work. I got this error: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of assigning the value in the declaration, assign the value in Start.  From your AI you can have a private Transform target; and in Start() assign target = PlayerManager.instance.player;  Your PlayerManager should assign the player variable from Awake to ensure that any calls from Start will refer to a value and not a null.  You can also change the type of player to Transform for ease of use.

Comment: The most likely reason you get a null reference is that `instance` is null.  This can happen when you attempt to access instance before instance has been set (i am guessing in Awake of PlayerManager).  Generally i will use a get in the static Instance property, it checks if the instance is null, if it is it searches the scene for the object of type using FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>().  if that is null, then there is none in the scene and you will have to act appropriately, either by creating a new GO with that component or throwing an exception.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0):

With `public GameObject player = PlayerManager.instance.player;` your field is initialized before the call of `EnemyController`'s constructor, and you provided no control over the value / definition state of `PlayerManager.instance.player` (PlayerManager or instance or player which can be null and is null in your case). So it's "too early" to use it.

Instead, you can use the event `playerJoinedEvent` in the [`PlayerInputManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Plugins.PlayerInput.PlayerInputManager.html) to assign the enemy to the played which just joined with an event handler, which checks that `PlayerManager` and `instance` and `player` are not null and then assign the player to the target.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I will try it and get back. Thank you

Comment: I managed to get it working with hijinxbassit's method but I will continue to look into this one. Thanks!